# How to custtomize PushNotificaion in xcode 4.2 in iphone?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have doubts about push notification.Can I customize PushNotification when I received. I want to calculate distance by getting current Geo points add/attach that distance with PushNotification in my app. Is it possible in iPhone? please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a little more? And why dont u use [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123)?

Comment: I have some geo points in db. I want to use that and current geo points to calculate distance. When Pushnotification comes from server i want show that distance with notification. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At very beginning, i couldn't understand your question exactly but APNS you can send specific information inside a push notification(even tough it is not a good idea). The payload of a push notification can be till 256 bytes, it works a a JSON dictionary an you can customize the dictionary as how you want. If i were you, i would follow steps below:

1. Customize your push notification body to send a specific position(as JSON)
2. Get the current position of your device and calculate the difference(or do what ever you want)
3. Show the difference of those variables(which had come from push and the one of the current position) in an alertview or something else..

Comment: Can you tell how i can Customize push notification? I just want to add/attach distance with coming push notification. And show in alertview. please help me if you know.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) link, i'm not sure how to customize the push but i will search for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notifiy your app if it is in background then APN is the only way.

Apple Push Notification is a replacement for background processing(App is in background).
As iPhone doesnot allow background processing more then 6 minute except VOIP or audio play.

So if You want to notify your app while it is in background state(Pause state). APN is the best way to notify the application. and you can paas 256 byte of data packet with APN.

Comment: Yes whatever your saying it is absolutely right. I am using same way. Now i want modify receive PushNotification. I want to attach calculating distance by saved geo points and current geo points and show that with PushNotification. Is it possible in iPhone?